# Do I need the chain specification file of Rococco testnet to run my local parachain node?

Tags: parachain, rococo, chainspec

I followed [Connect a local parachain](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/local-parachain/) tutorial and successfully run my local parachain node with this command:

```
./target/release/parachain-collator \
--alice \
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json \
--base-path /tmp/parachain/alice \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 8844 \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain <relay chain raw chain spec> \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977
```

But while follow [Connect to Rococo testnet](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/rococo-slot/) tutorial, I don't know how to fill the `<relay chain raw chain spec>` field to start local parachain node. Do I need the chain specification file of Rococco testnet to run my local parachain node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to connect your parachain to a relay chain you need its chain spec file.

In the tutorial, the relay chain you want to connect is rococo.
The chain spec is public: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/node/service/chain-specs/rococo.json

I suggest to download this file in your node and run the same command with:

```
--chain ./rococo.json \
```

You can see the spec files of other public networks: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/master/node/service/chain-specs